# Android 4 don't require unlock at home

Tags: security, lock-screens

In the Android OS version 4, what would I have to do to require a pass code to unlock the phone when I'm away from home, but when I'm at my home, I don't need pass-code restrictions.

Detecting proximity to my office could be done by detecting a WiFi or BlueTooth link to some hardware in the office, but GPS would be iffy since it doesn't work well inside. Also Google's location service would work, since it seems to know where my WiFi router is located very accurately.

I would also be interested to know whether this would be compatible with the full storage encryption on the Android.

Comment: As you report issues with encryption being involved, I want to make sure this works before making it an answer: you could try [Tasker](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/tasker/info) with the SecureSettings plugin. *Tasker* is a paid app, but they have a free trial on their homepage. SecureSettings has a free test version on Google Play. (and for more on *Tasker*, check my [list of Tasker resources](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/resources_tasker) to see it's worth considering to buy it :)

Answer (score 1):

[Skip lock screen](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.benhirashima.unlockwithwifi) (formerly "*Unlock with WiFi*") will let you bypass your device lock screen if you are connected to your home WiFi network. (Or whatever WiFi SSID you define.)

I used it a year or two ago and it worked well.

There is also [a trial version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.benhirashima.unlockwithwifitrial).

Comment: Neither "Unlock With WiFi" or "SkipLock" work if you have full device encryption enabled.

Comment: @tgharold just as it shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

Smart lock is a feature on Android 5.x and above but I'm not sure if it is on older Android versions. This allows your phone to be unlocked when your GPS shows you are at home, or you are connected to your home wifi.